# Rails: CanCan many roles per user can not save checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am following CanCan wiki to make my authorization. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

I did every step as the wiki says.
I can not save the value fields 'role' and 'roles_mask', every time I submit the form, they are nil. Anybody could tell me how to fix it?

**User schema**

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username",       
    t.string   "password_digest",
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "role"
    t.integer  "roles_mask"
  end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = OmsUser.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @saved = @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Success"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation,:role, :roles_mask)
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <% for role in User::ROLES %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][#{role}]", role, @user.roles.include?(role), {:name => "user[roles][]"}%>
    <%= label_tag "user_roles_#{role}", role.humanize %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ROLES = %w[admin user manager]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `user_params` you have not permitted `roles`:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, roles: [])
```

And in your `user` model did you add these methods:

```
# in models/user.rb
def roles=(roles)
  self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
end

def roles
  ROLES.reject do |r|
    ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
  end
end
```

These are also required to save the roles.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the codes in user model. I after adding roles:[ ] , the field roles_mask value can be saved, but the field of role is still nil. Is there anything still not correct ?

Comment: You don't need to add the `role` column in the database. Only `role_mask` will do the job. Now just try fetching `user.roles` it should return you the roles.

Comment: It works! To be honest. I do not understand why I added a roles_mask field, but I need to put roles:[ ] inside strong parameter and how does it generated roles:[ ].  Could you please let me know how does the magic happens or where I can go to learn it ?

Comment: What is the exact value saved in database in bit format? I have never used bitmask but I can try and help if I can

Comment: when user.roles = ['zeng','shan'], then in database the value of roles_mask is 3

Comment: I think it saves according to this link: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18169 which says For example, suppose in a set of 5 objects, we have picked the 1st , 3rd , and 4th object. The bitmask to represent this in binary is 01101 or 13 in decimal (in the notes, the 1 st bit will always be the least significant bit and will always appear at the very right).